# Controlling .exe parameters in c# .net

Tags: c#-4.0, parameter-passing

I want to control parameters of .exe file when it runs again. For example

**DocumentViewer.exe** -DocID=1097911 -DBName "TEST.WORLD" -DBUname "DB1" -DBPwd "DB1" -AccessUserName "user1" -AccessPassword "pass1" -AccessPath "C:\..."

While this .exe file is running if user runs a new instance of .exe file with different DocID, I want to inform user "You should complete your work with DocID:1097911 to open new document".

I don't understand where should I get second instance's parameters to control with the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some type of data store in order to save the parameters. Then after the instance is terminated you need to clear out the data store. In this example i'm going to use a text file for simplicity.

when an instance of your .exe is started, first read from a centralized text file. If the text file is empty then update the file with the instance's parameters and continue starting. If its not empty then notify the user with the DocId from the text file.